# How to upload a txt file using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, file, automation, cypress

I can't upload a txt file using cypress, the test passes but the file won't upload. I´m usig the cypress-file-upload plugin. My file is in the fixtures folder.

This is the html code snippet
[image: This is the html code snippet:]

This is the function I have:

[image: This is the function I have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an `input` tag of `type="file"` ? If not try it. So instead of doing

```
cy.get('.col-xs-12 > .btn')
```

you could try

```
cy.get('#id-of-input-tag')
```

Comment: There is no input tag, the html code of the button is: <button type="buton" class="btn btn-primary  ng-scope"....

Comment: Correction, it exists, it was just hidden.